# Affect on classification for two different Sentinel images taken at the same time with slightly different color values

Tags: raster, classification, land-use, copernicus, sentinel

I am running a supervised land-use land-change classification across multiple Sentinel images. These images were taken at the same time of different but overlapping areas. However, despite being taken at the same time, they have slightly different color values for the same features. I suspect this is due to the angle at which the different photos were taken. Will this affect my classification?